# JPA one-to-one bidirectional mapping on same object using association table

Tags: jpa, one-to-one, bidirectional

I have a table Person and now I want to express a relation like "best friend". Assuming a person can only have one best friend I don't want to alter the Person table to add a best friend column, rather I want to have an additional mapping table, e.g.:

---

Table Person (id name):

---

1 foo

2 bar

3 somebody

4 somebodyelse

---

Table BestFriendMapping (personId bestfriendId):

---

1 2

3 4

I was doing something like this:

```
class Person {
  @OneToOne()
  @Fetch(FetchMode.SELECT)
  @JoinTable(name = "BestFriendMapping",
        joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "personId", referencedColumnName = "id"),
        inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "bestfriendId",
        referencedColumnName = "id"))
  private Person bestFriend;
}
```

The problem is, that now when I add a new Person, the mapping table is populated with two entries, for example the newly added Person is having id=10 and his bestFriend 20, then the entries are:

10 20

20 10

I would like to have just one entry, but still be able to get the best friend of a person no matter which I have in my hand currently. I found out that I probably have done two unidirectional instead of one bi-directional mapping, so I have to use mappedBy, but I am not sure what is the syntax when it is about the one and the same entity object, thus one and the same field inside the object. The examples on the internet are always showing the mapping of two entities via a mapping table.
Or maybe something like this?!? In addition to the JoinColumns and InverseJoinColumns to add mappedBy to the OnetoOne just like this `@OneToOne(mappedBy="bestFriend")`, kind of weird :)

Comment: This is not possible, as there is no way to tell which person gets put in as the ID and which is the bestFriendId - you need to have an owning relationship and an 'other' side (aka a bidirectional relationship), maybe a befriendedBy type mapping that then allows your application to decide who is the id and who is the bestFriend.  Also note that my best friend might not consider me their 'best' friend. They could be much more out going and have many friends, where I could be a socially inept loaner with just the one. The relationship seems better suited to be an ordered ManyToMany of friends.

Comment: "Also note that my best friend might not consider me their 'best' friend" - don't take the example to the real world :) In this case the relation is symmetric. Ok, if you think it is not possible, is it then ok, how is it now? Cause it is working, just I wondered whether it is fine to get alway 2 entries created on every new relation?

Comment: Right, I just mentioned that because of the way you are mapping it and to help show why you are getting two entries in the join table - you are adding Bob to Bill's list of friends (or singular best friend reference). It is a , and then Bill to Bob's list of friends. Each reference requires a separate entry in the join table. You can use the mappedby if you want to show the other side of such a reference, and hide the fact there are two references  from the application.

Comment: ok, ok, when you say "you can use mappedBy", if I use it am I going to have only one entry in the mapping table then?

Comment: @Chris can you reply to my previous question pls, thanks

Comment: I don't understand your comment, and you are better off going to the docs to find out what mappedby is used for, but.. it is used to mark one side of a bidirectional relationship as being 'mappedby' the other side. In a bidirectional OneToOne for instance, there will only be one foreign key. One side has control of setting this foreign key value, while the other states it is 'mappedby' or controlled through the otherside of the relationship. It is essentially read-only as changes will not affect the foreign key. It works the same for 1:M and M:M relationships.